# Flattening hash into string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a way to flatten a hash into a string, with optional delimiters between keys and values, and key/value pairs?

For example, `print {:a => :b, :c => :d}.flatten('=','&')` should print `a=b&c=d`

I wrote some code to do this, but I was wondering if there was a neater way:

```
class Hash
  def flatten(keyvaldelimiter, entrydelimiter)
    string = ""
    self.each do
      |key, value|
      key = "#{entrydelimiter}#{key}" if string != "" #nasty hack
      string += "#{key}#{keyvaldelimiter}#{value}"  
    end
    return string
  end
end

print {:a => :b, :c => :d}.flatten('=','&') #=> 'c=d&a=b'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I wouldn't override `.flatten`, which is already defined:

> Returns a new array that is a
>   one-dimensional flattening of this
>   hash. That is, for every key or value
>   that is an array, extract its elements
>   into the new array. Unlike
>   Array#flatten, this method does not
>   flatten recursively by default. If the
>   optional level argument determines the
>   level of recursion to flatten.

This is simplest way to do it that I'm aware of:

```
{:a => 100, :b => 200}.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')
# => "a=100&b=200"
```

Comment: You can further simplify this. See my answer for details. The gist is to replace `|k, v|` with `|e|` which makes `e` an array that you can call `e.join('=')` on.

Comment: how to do the reverse to get a hash

Comment: I prefer `{ a: 100, b: 200 }.map {|h| h.join '=' }.join '&'`. Just a little cleaner.

Answer (score 22):

Slight variation of @elektronaut's version:

You can actually put just an `|e|` there instead of `|k, v|` in which case `e` is an array of two elements and you can call `e.join('=')`. Altogether you have something like

```
class Hash
  def join(keyvaldelim=$,, entrydelim=$,) # $, is the global default delimiter
    map {|e| e.join(keyvaldelim) }.join(entrydelim)
  end
end

{a: 100, b: 200}.join('=', '&') # I love showing off the new Ruby 1.9 Hash syntax
# => 'a=100&b=200'
```

Comment: I would seriously question how smart it is to monkey patch `Hash`, especially with a non-namespaced method name like `join`. While I expect this from many, I'm very surprised to see such suggestion from a very experienced dev.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to generate a url query string, you most certainly should use a method like activesupport's to_param (aliased to to_query). Imagine the problems if you had an ampersand or equal sign in the data itself.

to_query takes care of escaping:

```
>> require 'active_support/core_ext/object'
>> {'a&' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'}.to_query
>> => "a%26=b&c=d"
```

**EDIT**

@fahadsadah makes a good point about not wanting to load Rails. Even active_support/core_ext/object will load 71 files. It also monkey-patches core classes.

A lightweight and cleaner solution:

```
require 'rack'  # only loads 3 files
{'a&' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'}.map{|pair|
  pair.map{|e| Rack::Utils.escape(e.to_s) }.join('=')
}.join('&')
# => "a%26=b&c=d"
```

It's important to escape, otherwise the operation isn't reversible.

Comment: That's all very well, and it's a good point, but I'd rather not require Rails to be installed when I created the source hash

Comment: Rails for the win!!

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do it with standard methods and arrays:

```
class Hash
  def flatten(keyvaldelimiter, entrydelimiter)
    self.map { |k, v| "#{k}#{keyvaldelimiter}#{v}" }.join(entrydelimiter)
  end
end
```

You might also be interested in the [Rails `to_query` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions.html#M000822).

Also, obviously, you can write `"#{k}#{keyvaldelimiter}#{v}"` as `k.to_s + keyvaldelimiter + v.to_s`...

Comment: Or `[k,v].join(keyvaldelimiter)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a built-in way, but here's some shorter code:

```
class Hash
  def flatten(kvdelim='', entrydelim='')
    self.inject([]) { |a, b| a << b.join(kvdelim) }.join(entrydelim)
  end
end

puts ({ :a => :b, :c => :d }).flatten('=', '&') # => a=b&c=d
```

Answer (score 0):

What about getting it in JSON format. That way the format is clear.

There are lots of JSON tools for ruby. Never tried them, though. But the output will then of course slide into javascript, etc easier. Likely one line.

The big savings, though would be in documentation, in that you will need much less.